# Heroku not showing my assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I've precompiled my assets on my local machine, yet when I pushed it to heroku, all my assets are no longer available, they don't seem to have compiled.

I recently had to reinstall rails/ruby/rvm and this is when the error started occurring.

Let me know if I can give you any more information.

Answer (score 0):

In /config/environments/production. set:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```